# Please check the following program: in this I can only replace a character 'x' but I want to replace a word. How to do that?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def translator(phrase):
    translate = ""
    for letter in phrase:
        if letter in "x":
            translate = translate + "Awesome"
        else:
            translate = translate + letter

    return translate


print (translator(input("enter your phrase: ")))
```

Output of the above program:

> enter your phrase: everyday is x day
>
> everyday is Awesome day

Expected output:

> Enter your phrase: everyday is a good day
>
> everyday is a Awesome day

Comment: `replace()` method?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace a word in a string, you can use `.split()` function- which returns a list of the words in the string and `.join` function- which concatenate any number of strings with a chosen string between the strings.
For example:

```
sentence = "This is a sentence"
word_list = sentence.split()
print(word_list)
sentence = "$".join(word_list)
```

Output:
`["This", "is", "a", "sentence"]`
`enter code here`

In the program above, you can use it this way:

```
def translator(phrase):
    words_list = phrase.split()
    words_list[2] = "Awesome"
    return " ".join(words_list)

print (translator(input("enter your phrase: ")))
```